# Amazon SNS Intermittent utf-8 encoding issue

Tags: utf-8, jetty, rabbitmq, amazon-sns, intermittent

We are having a strange intermittent problem when dealing with utf-8 characters being rendered as �. Somedays we send messages using international characters (ie ü) and users receive the correct message and other days the ü becomes �.  We are using Jetty running with (JAVA_OPTIONS+=("-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8")) as an endpoint to publish messages to a queue (rabbitmq) which is consumed by another jetty instance that interfaces with amazon sns to push these message via (gcm and apns) to android and ios users. We are using running all of this on aws instances. Does anyone have a clue where in our system this intermittent issue could be happening.